# adobe AIR native application menu question

Tags: actionscript-3, air

HI, I', trying to add some menuItems to an AIR app application menu in the mac, I know that is possible to add to the standard one the application have instead of replace the whole menu, but I can't found any example on adding not replacing the whole the menu, can someone be kind on point me to an example of how to do that, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a post I found just doing a quick google search:

http://www.thanksmister.com/index.php/archive/air-adding-application-menu-bar-items/

I've created application menus for many applications, and it works just as described in this post (not written by me).